# JSon file reading

Tags: json, file

Hi I want to read a JSON file from java code under linux environment but it is throwing error. Code snippet is-

```
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

  Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/hipad/hipad/UserProject/" +sessionName+"/" + Cluster + "/" + selProjectToBring + "/metadata.txt");
```

**ERROR :**
         Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 322.
         at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:146)
         at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)

What is the problem with code, any suggestion ...

Comment: sounds like there is syntax error in json file. Could you paste the content of the JSON here?

Comment: It sounds as if your file actually contains multiple json objects.

Comment: @Icarus3 ... content of file...{"projectToCompile":"ppppppoo","selcedLang":"","CProjectFolderName":"ppppppoo","programContent":"\n#include<stdio.h>\n\nint main()\n{\nprintf(\"dev\");\nreturn 0;\n}\n\n@@","isHybridProject":"NO","TypeOfProject":"C","Filename":"op[.c,","clusterSelected":"SIMPLE","projectFolderNameForCompilation":"ppppppoo"}{"dinesh":"ppppppoo"}

Comment: @RogerLindsjö ...Thanks alot, my mistake, you are right file is having multiple json data, now its working.